# Why does MySQL return results that don't appear to match the query?

Tags: mysql

Given the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `pk` smallint NOT NULL,
  `vc` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test` (`pk`, `vc`) VALUES
(1, '3A61034C-A476-4615-9759-BC39F82DC511'),
(2, '4X227');

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pk`);
```

If I run the following queries I get unexpected results:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE vc=3;
  result: 1,3A61034C-A476-4615-9759-BC39F82DC511

SELECT * FROM test WHERE vc=4;
  result: 2,4X227

SELECT * FROM test WHERE vc=5;
  (no results)
```

I see that it gets results where vc starts with the number being queried for, but I don't understand why it would behave that way. I would have expected no results for all three queries. I have reproduced this in MySQL 5.6,5.7 and 8.0.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7c63d51b104d5da303314c332e2ec20

Comment: *I don't understand why it would behave that way.* Study [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing numbers with strings, MySQL will convert strings into numbers for comparison

Comment: I came across this as a bug in some code that uses prepared statements. The code was looking for an integer but the field it was looking in was a varchar. I hadn't noticed that the type of parameter was based on the parameter type instead of the field type. The SQL I pasted here was based off of that app and code, so my mind hadn't even registered the type conversion! Thanks.